# BQ load JSON File with Array of Array

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

Im trying to load a JOSN file where some of the arrays are empty.

```
{"house_account_payable":"0.00","house_account_receivable":"0.00","gift_sales_payable":"0.00","gift_sales_receivable":"0.00","store_credit_sales_payable":"0.00","percentage_row":null,"sales_per_period":[["02:00AM - 02:59AM",{"amount":0,"qty":0}],["03:00AM - 03:59AM",{"amount":0,"qty":0}]],"revenue_centers":[],"tax_breakdowns":[]}
```

This is giving the error:

```
rror while reading table: test2, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No object found when new array is started.; BeginArray returned false; Parser terminated before end of string
```

Could somebody help me on this?

Comment: The opening and close of the object {.....} should be in the same line. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54658959/132438 for a fix

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I have updated the complete JSON file, it is nested actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with the null arrays.

The problem lies in this shorter json:

`{"sales_per_period":[["02:00AM - 02:59AM",{"amount":0,"qty":0}],["03:00AM - 03:59AM",{"amount":0,"qty":0}]]}`

The arrays there hold elements of different types, and to bring it into a structured table, a different schema is needed.

For example:

`{"sales_per_period":[{"a":"02:00AM - 02:59AM","b":{"amount":0,"qty":0}},{"a":"03:00AM - 03:59AM","b":{"amount":0,"qty":0}}]}`

Now this loads easily into BigQuery:

`bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect temp.short delete.short.json`

[image]

Can you change this source JSON easily outside BigQuery? Otherwise load it raw into BigQuery, and parse it with a JS UDF inside BigQuery.

Comment: I tried to load it with string, but it didn't Work, I'm fine with loading Raw data. But what data type should i use?

Comment: load as `csv`, with a custom field delimiter `\0`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load data from your local machine or GCS? Please, remember about exporting in `JSONL(Newline delimited JSON)`:

```
{"open_orders_ids": []}
{"unpaid_orders_ids": []}
```

The output:

[image]

Take a look for [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated) about nested and repeated columns.

**EDIT:**

Your JSON schema should look like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "house_account_payable": "0.00",
            "house_account_receivable": "0.00",
            "gift_sales_payable": "0.00",
            "gift_sales_receivable": "0.00",
            "store_credit_sales_payable": "0.00",
            "percentage_row": "",
            "sales_per_period": [
                {
                    "AM02_00_AM02_59": {
                        "amount": "0",
                        "qty": "0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "AM03_00_AM03_59": {
                        "amount": "0",
                        "qty": "0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Regarding to Felipe Hoffa's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657231/turning-json-blob-into-bq-friendly-format-with-jq/54658959#54658959), run following commands:

```
jq -c  .items[] <FILENAME>.json  > <FILENAME>.jq.json
bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect <DATASET_ID>.<TABLENAME> <FILENAME>.jq.json
```

The schema:

[image]

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full JSON file.

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know about the results.